# Working with Threads and a Semaphore in Java - how does "acquire()" work?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm currently enrolled in an introductory Java course for "advanced" (by the standards of our university's CS program) programmers.  While none of the concepts we've worked with thus far have been radically different, I'm confused about the utility of Semaphores- I'm supposed to use a (or more than one?) Semaphore to ensure that only five threads execute in sequence at any given time.  Because of where I am I can't test if my program is headed in the right direction right now, but I just need to figure out how Semaphore.acquire() works:

Since "acquire()" is the semaphore's method, and it doesn't take a thread (or anything) as an argument, how do you "select" a thread to acquire a permit? Does it automatically apply the permit to the thread referenced immediately previously? This is basically how I'm trying to do it now:

```
Thread selected = threads[int next_thread_to_add];
mySemaphore.acquire();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple `Semaphore` sample. By using the `Semaphore` you can pass a `Semaphore` object to decide how many threads can concurrency run.

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    Semaphore semaphore;
    public Test(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Test(semaphore));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Test(semaphore));
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Test(semaphore));
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(new Test(semaphore));
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println("Hello World: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            semaphore.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the only things you ever do to explicitly specified `Thread` are `t.start()` and `t.join()`.  Most other operations on a thread are things that the thread implicitly does to _itself_.  For example, `semaphore.acquire()` acquires one permit _for the calling thread_.

Answer (score 0):

the currently running thread that calls the mySemaphoer.acquire() gets the permit. You dont select the thread, the semaphore does, the 'selected' thread simply advances past the acquire() call. Other wait till they became 'selected'

Comment: thanks!  I thought it might be something like this- none of the resources I checked seemed to suggest the call was made from within a thread

Comment: all the code is always called from within a thread, a thread executes the code. In simple 'standard one thread' application it is the main thread that has started the program exectuion. If you start new threads, their start with their 'own' code to begin with (content of the run method)

Answer (score 0):

> Since "acquire()" is the semaphore's method, and it doesn't take a thread (or anything) as an argument, how do you "select" a thread to acquire a permit?

You will want to use the `.aquire()` method of your Semaphore **before** executing a code block that you want to be **synchronized**. At the end of the **synchronized** code block, use the `.release()` method so that another thread may then acquire the Semaphore.

> Does it automatically apply the permit to the thread referenced immediately previously?

No, whatever thread is running will attempt to acquire() a permit from the Semaphore once it reaches the line `mySemaphore.acquire();`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire()

As is the case whenever using semaphores or locks - be careful to avoid [deadlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html).